# Linq join returning parent even when child is null

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2015

I want to select all rows where fake2 is null AND all rows with a join on fake2
The code below does it fine, but I want to do it all in a select linq query to increase efficiency.

```
var rows = (
            from a in crmLinqContext.fakeSet
            join b in crmLinqContext.fake2Set on a.fake2.Id equals b.Id
            join c in crmLinqContext.fake3Set on b.field equals c.field
            where c.anotherField == "THIS_BIT_OF_TEXT"
            select a);

List<myObject> objects = new List<myObject>();
foreach(var row in rows)
{
    objects.Add(row);
}
 rows = (
    from a in crmLinqContext.fakeSet
    where s.fake2 == null
    select a);

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    objects.Add(row);
}
return objects;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join in linq something like below, it is not tested but what it does is that it left outer joins fakeSet and fakeSet2.

```
var rows =
    from a in crmLinqContext.fakeSet
    join b in crmLinqContext.fake2Set on a.fake2.Id equals b.Id into subset
    from b in subset.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join c in crmLinqContext.fake3Set on b.field equals c.field
    where c.anotherField == "THIS_BIT_OF_TEXT"
    select a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = (
            from a in crmLinqContext.fakeSet
            join b in crmLinqContext.fake2Set on a.Id equals b.Id
            join c in crmLinqContext.fake3Set on b.field equals c.field
            where c.anotherField == "THIS_BIT_OF_TEXT"
            select a)
            .Concat(
            from a1 in crmLinqContext.fakeSet
            where a1.fake2 == null
            select a1);
```

Comment: Does this not run two queries concatenating the results?